# Mac/PC hybrid CD ISO to USB?

Tags: macos, usb, iso-image, dd, fat32

I have a once-a-year project that I work on around this time every year, which consists of a set of HTML and CSS files (kind of like a saved copy of a website) that get distributed on professionally duplicated DVDs. I create the DVDs using Toast in OS X.

The trickiest part of these DVDs is that there are different files for the Mac "view" of the disk, and different for the Windows "view". This stems from the desire of my client to have a nicely displaying disk icon and Finder window (complete with custom background image) for when the disc is inserted into a Mac, and for Windows users to run autorun.inf (which just launches index.html in the default browser).

The HTML files on the Mac side needed to be hidden away (so they are called .html so that Finder doesn't display them), whereas on the Windows side my client isn't as picky since autorun.inf kicks in as soon as you insert the disc.

So I've been doing this process once a year for four years now and have the process pretty much sorted. I can reliably create these discs with the help of some special Finder-modifying tools (for the background images and disc icons on the Desktop) and having the same disc insert into two different OSes and to show two sets of files.

My client this year wants to distribute a USB key instead of a DVD. After some extensive Googling, I just can't seem to make this work. Googling for 'hybrid iso to usb' gives me a lot of information about how to make a bootable USB key for Linux installations, which doesn't really fit with what I'm trying to do.

The closest I have gotten to my CD-to-USB conversion is to save out my Toast project to a .toast file in OSX, rename this to .iso, convert that to .img and then use dd to write the .img file out straight to /dev/diskN (N being my USB drive). I have done this with a test .toast file that has only one file on the Mac side (a 768KB JPG) and a 219KB PDF on the Windows side.

However this seems to only write out the Mac portion of the Toast image file, and when I plug the USB drive into Windows, it doesn't see the Windows side at all -- the rest of the USB drive I am using (a 2GB flash drive) just stays unpartitioned.

I also tried just making two partitions (one FAT32, the other HFS+) and using the SetFile trick (from an [apple.stackexchange post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56429/how-to-create-a-hidden-partition-on-a-hard-drive)) but this doesn't work. It seems when I mount the drive on Windows, this hidden bit gets reset somehow.

Has anyone done anything like this before, and is it even possible?

Comment: None of those answers really work in my case. Additionally, the responses saying that NTFS drives won't mount in OSX is untrue. I see both partitions in OSX.